# How can I get rid of 1mb of unallocated space at the end of this table? (Gparted - see screenshot)

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I can't seem to find a way to extend or move this 1mb, but it's really bugging me.

[image]

Comment: To whoever has voted to close this as *too localized*: This happens all the time (though not 100% of the time), take a look at GParted screenshots anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that with GUID partitioning, as your disk probably uses, the final 1MB is a copy of the partition table.  From wikipedia: "GPT also provides redundancy, writing the GPT header and partition table both at the beginning and at the end of the disk."  If this is the case, you can't reuse it.

But why worry about 1MB in 112GB?

Comment: Because that shows up as unallocated space and is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the clutter of a dual/multiboot disk. The partitions, especially with Windows utilizing multiple recovery partitions now too, become a clutter and sometimes separate key areas of the disk. Being able to remove 1MB separating other partitions is about just that.. partition clutter.. not space. It is not even the size of an old floppy disc, so this is pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks but this is more than 3 years old and I've long since moved past it!

Comment: @AdamShort It is still valid to post answers to old questions, as they might help new users facing similar issues. Notice also that there is no accepted answer. Did any of the answers solved your problem? If so, mark it as solved, for reference to others.

Comment: Ha! Ha! "Not even the size of an old floppy disk"... Well... depends which ones. When I started I had 144Kb disks... and these were the extended version.

Comment: @AdamShort, please recommend me a good therapist to help me also move past it :)

Answer (score 0):

So, because I couldn't move past it, I used `fdisk` to make unallocated space smaller, maybe not to the last kilobyte but at least it doesn't show up anymore to disturb me.

This is just for the last partition, I already have GPT and other partitions.

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdaX # whatever is device path

Command (m for help): n
Partition number (18-128, default 18): # I just hit enter here
First sector (38654707712-39063650270, default 38654707712): # just hit enter
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (38654707712-39063650270, default 39063648255): 39063650269

Created a new partition 18 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 195 GiB.
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

The important value was `39063650269`. I calculated the difference between the max end value of `39063650270` and the default end value of `39063648255` to `2015` sectors.

This disk has 512 bytes sectors. So `2015 * 512` makes some `1007.5MiB`.

I was too lazy to calculate the precise location for GPT second copy but thought half a MB should suffice. So `1007 * 1024 / 512` is `2014` sectors.

And the final value is the default `end` value + `2014` sectors. `39063648255 + 2014 = 39063650269`.

Now gparted doesn't show unallocated space anymore.

.. for whoever is interested in worthless exercises.